# $cordovaCamera detect when the user cancells the photo

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using the $ cordovaCamera plugin, and I want to detect when the user cancels the photo. When I run the device's native camera, there are 2 options, save or cancel the photo. I want it when I choose the option of not saving the photo, ie canceling it, i need put a code instruction, for example a $state.go()

```
  var options = {
     quality: 100,
     destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
     sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
     allowEdit: true,
     encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
     targetWidth: 300,
     targetHeight: 300,
     popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
     saveToPhotoAlbum: true
   };

   //this metod only works when the photo is taken
   $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
   }, function (err) {   

   });
```